# mysql ınsert query dosen't workıng sometımes

Tags: php, mysql, sql-insert

I have a strange ıssue wıth mysql ınsert query wıth php ıt's usually workıng but when ı ınsert some texts does not workıng and **no reason**
so ı do not why the code dose not runing .
my database varibales and connection is correct  becuse its running in other inputs

```
   require_once('conn.php');
if (isset($_GET['book'])) {
    
    $book=$_GET['book'];
    $id=$_GET['id'];
}






if (isset($_POST["sub"])) {
//inputs*********************
$bookName=$_POST['bookName'];

//category configuration
$category_ar=$_POST['category_ar'];
$category_en=$_POST['category_en'];
$category_tr=$_POST['category_tr'];

$author=$_POST['author'];

//description configuration
$description_ar=$_POST['desc_ar'];
$description_en=$_POST['desc_en'];
$description_tr=$_POST['desc_tr'];


//extensions configuration
$bookEx=explode('.',$book);
$ex=strtolower(end($bookEx));




$caption=$bookName;


//image 

$image=$_FILES['image']['name'];
$image_temp=$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$imageSize   =$_FILES['image']['size'];
$imageError  =$_FILES['image']['error'];
$imageType   =$_FILES['image']['type'];
$image_target_path= "uploads/covers/".$image;

// -------------
$bookName="[YOUR_CLOSE_BOOK]". $bookName.".".$ex;
$bookPath="uploads/BOOKS/".$bookName;
echo $book."                                      ".$bookPath;
if (copy($book,$bookPath) && move_uploaded_file($image_temp,$image_target_path)) {

$insert = $db->multi_query("INSERT INTO maintable1(author,file_name,image_name,description_ar,description_tr,description_en,caption,category_ar,category_tr,category_en,uploaded_on,vote,voted)
VALUES('$author','$bookName','$image','$description_ar','$description_tr','$description_en','$caption','$category_ar','$category_tr','$category_en',NOW(),0,0);
UPDATE user_uploads SET sorted='true' where id=$id; ");

 
if($insert){
   
   echo "<script>window.location.href='sort.php?suc&file=$bookName';</script>";
  
}
else{
    echo"nooooooooooooo";
}
}
else {
    echo"  SOME ERROR";
}


   
}
```

other code

```
<div class="box">
        <form action="u.php?book=<?php echo $book?>&id=<?php echo $id?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="text"  name="bookName" placeholder="أسم الكتاب" required>
            <div class="select">

            <!-- SELECT ONE -->
            <select name="category_ar" id="category_ar" onchange="ch()">
            <option value="">اختر فئة</option>
           
                    <?php
                    require_once 'conn.php';
                    $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM categores ORDER BY category_ar");
                    $category_ar;
                    if($query->num_rows > 0){
                        while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
                            $category_ar = $row["category_ar"];
                        
                    ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $category_ar;?>"><?php echo $category_ar;?></option>
                    
                    <?php }
                    }else{ ?>
                    <p>No image(s) found...</p>
                    <?php } ?>
            </select>

            <!-- SELECT TOW-->
            <select name="category_en" id="category_en">
            <option value="">اختر فئة</option>
            
                    <?php
                    require_once 'conn.php';
                    $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM categores ORDER BY category_ar");
                    $category_en;
                    if($query->num_rows > 0){
                        while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
                            $category_en = $row["category_en"];
                        
                    ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $category_en;?>"><?php echo $category_en;?></option>
                    
                    <?php }
                    }else{ ?>
                    <p>No image(s) found...</p>
                    <?php } ?>
            </select>

            <!-- SELECT THREE -->
            <select name="category_tr" id="category_tr">
            <option value="">اختر فئة</option>
          
                    <?php
                    require_once 'conn.php';
                    $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM categores ORDER BY category_ar;");
                    $category_tr;
                    if($query->num_rows > 0){
                        while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
                            $category_tr = $row["category_tr"];
                        
                    ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $category_tr;?>"><?php echo $category_tr;?></option>
                    
                    <?php }
                    }else{ ?>
                    <p>No image(s) found...</p>
                    <?php } ?>
            </select>
            <a class="add" href="http://yourclosebook.com/addCategory" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">add</a>
            </div>
        
            <input type="text" name="author" placeholder="الكاتب" required>
            <textarea name="desc_ar" id="" placeholder="وصف عربي" required ></textarea>
            <textarea name="desc_en" id="" placeholder="وصف انجليزي" required ></textarea>
            <textarea name="desc_tr" id="" placeholder="وصف تركي" required ></textarea>
            <input type="file" name="image" id="image" placeholder="الغلاف"  required>
            <input type="submit" value="تحميل" name="sub" id="sub">
        
        </form>

    
    </div>
```

**my input is**

GAZİ TÖMER A2

GAZİ ÜNİVERSİTESİ

كتاب تعلم اللغة التركية المستوى الثاني من جامعة غازي التركية العريقة
يتناول هذا الكتاب أسس المحادثة اليومية مع توسع في اسلوب السرد
بالقواعد متوسطة في اللغة التركية

Turkish language learning book, second level from the ancient Turkish University of Gazi
This book covers the foundations of daily conversation with an expansion of narration style
The rules are intermediate in Turkish

Türk dili öğrenme kitabı, Gazi antik Türk Üniversitesi'nden ikinci seviye
Bu kitap, anlatım stilini genişleterek günlük konuşmanın temellerini kapsar
Türkçe'de kurallar orta düzeydedir

Comment: **Warning!** You are _wide open_ for [SQL injection](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection) attacks! You should use parameterized [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of using completely unescaped user data directly in your queries like that. _Never ever ever never_ trust user input.

Comment: I'm very sure there is a reason though. If you set up proper [error handling](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) when you execute your queries, it will be easier to pinpoint the specific issue when they fail. And the SQL injection issue is extra important when using multi query.

Comment: this panel only for me .ıts like management panel to sort the books and give ıt an dıscriptıon

Comment: That doesn't matter. If you're not escaping your data, you're introducing a ton of ways for the queries to fail. If they contains some specific characters, the generated string (the query) can be broken. Just a simple example: If you're posting some text that contains a single quote (for example "I'm here"), this: `'$foo'` would be generated as: `'I'm home'`. As you see, the quoting is off and MySQL will throw errors when trying to parse `m home` since it's not outside of the quotes.

Comment: prepared satatements can solve this kind error?

Comment: Yes. Prepared statements with placeholders doesn't generate a query with the data injected. It sends the statement, like: `VALUES (?, ?, ?)` and the values separately to the server. So escaping (not needed with prepared statements) and prepared statements aren't just for security. But you should still add some proper error handling.

Comment: ok thank you very much i will try it ı had use in other pages so ı'll do it again

Comment: it's **works** thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must use prepared statement to solve this problem